# how to fix "no module named openpyxl " in (pycharm) python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.7

I was trying to add excel spreadsheets so i had to import openpyxl command which throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prasad/PycharmProjects/test/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl as xl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

i tried **pip3 install openpyxl** , but it didn't rectify the error.

Comment: @AnkushRasgon It's mentioned in question.

Comment: This might be more of software issue. Pycharm might be pointing to a different environment. Did you run directly from terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I created a file call `test.py` to help you to install any module using [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and I ran it from `Ctrl + Shift + F10`. Then I get this error which you already got.

[image]

Just click on `openpyxl` and you'll see some [red bulb](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html#Intention_Actions.xml). Just click it or enter `Alt + Enter` keywords, you'll get below image.

[image]

Just click the `install package openpyxl` and it will be installing to your machine.

[image]

After that you'll get this notification, if you get this mean it successfully installed in to your computer and now your error should be gone (in the import statement).

[image]

I think your problem is solved. Like this you can install any package using [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) in your current environment which is setup to run your program. For more information check this [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#Installing_Uninstalling_and_Upgrading_Packages.xml) article from [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) official.